# three dependeant parameters in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am completely newbie in prolog.SO please anybody guide me the correct way i should go!
I have two parameters CctypeInt and Ru1
the relation below says :
if CctypeInt is 0 then Ru1 is a list {2,3,4} and if CctypeInt is 1 Ru1 is a list {2,3,4} and CctypeInt is 2 Ru1 is a list with one element {2}

```
relation(CctypeInt,[0-{2,3,4}, 1-{2,3,4}, 2-{2}],Ru1),
```

everything is working fine here.
but there is a third parameter which can take the values as explained below:

```
(
CctypeInt is 0 then Ru2 is -1
    ;CctypeInt is 1 and Ru1 is  2 then Ru2 is [2,3,4]
    ;CctypeInt is 1 and Ru1  is  3 then Ru2 is [2,3]
    ;CctypeInt is 1 and Ru1  is  4 then Ru2 is 2
    ;CctypeInt is 2 then Ru1 is 2 then Ru2 is 2
    ),!.
```

i tried the below code for the same.

```
        (
CctypeInt=:=0->Ru2 is -1
    ;CctypeInt=:=1,Ru1 =:= 2->Ru2 is [2,3,4]
    ;CctypeInt=:=1,Ru1 =:= 3->Ru2 is [2,3]
    ;CctypeInt=:=1,Ru1 =:= 4->Ru2 is 2
    ;CctypeInt=:=2->Ru1 is 2,Ru2 is 2
    ),!.
```

but i am getting an error like 
CctypeInt is a range 0..2 and cannot be compared.

Comment: So, is `CctypeInt` a range? Have you tried printing it?

Comment: Yes its a range ...and using that range i am correctly extracting the range of Ru1 but since Ru2 is dependant on both cctypeint and Ru1 i am having this problem of writing the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but this would seem to do the job:

```
% relation(CctypeInt, Ru1, Ru2)

relation(1,2,[2,3,4]).
relation(1,3,[2,3]).
relation(1,4,2).
relation(2,2,2).
```